# Adding methods to a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object that's the argument of a function.

I want to add methods to those objects, so I can easily perform operations on them.

How do I add those methods to the object?

```
stuff.on('move', function (element) {
    element.remove()
    element.add()
    element.change()
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element.remove = function(){
    ...
};
```

Comment: For some reason, I remember reading that older versions of IE wouldn't let you do stuff like this. Am I making that up? Also, would there be a problem with using `element.prototype.remove`, or is that where older browsers draw the line.